# Develop application to run on ESXi 5.0

Tags: esxi

1. Is it possible to develop 3rd party apps that will be run on the ESXI 5.0 host machine? For example, daemon that monitor the ESXi machine.
2. Is it possible to compile application on Red Hat Linux and then install them on the ESXi machine? Should we use specific development environment?
3. Where can I get information regarding development for ESXi?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for : http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toolchain provide by VMware. WMware provides 3 different version toolchains for their OSes.

ex. ESXi 5.5 toolchain
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=ESXI550_OSS&productId=353

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only what you need to do is to compile your application with static. And yet one: with vmware esxi, there is only a very limited /proc!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you probably want to do kernel module or userworld development.
Typically, only vmware partner can get the vShpere kmdk devkit. Please find more info here https://developercenter.vmware.com/dcpn-faq.